# Two comparison operators in c++ like python

Tags: python, c++, logic, comparison-operators

Does the comparison `5 > x > 1` work in C++, like it does in python. It doesn't show any compiling errors but also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It works fine. Can you show a failing example?

Comment: `((795 > x > 4) && (595 > y > 4))` this condition returns false even when (x,y) is (400,300)

Comment: @GarbageCollector The question wasn't whether it work's *fine*, the question was whether it works the same as it does in python, to which the answer is a clear "no".

Comment: @Zinki can you please elaborate on the difference between the two language's working?

Comment: @Vikramark: The answer by Bathsheba below makes the difference for this particular case clear quite well. If you want to know the differences in usage between the languages in the general case, that is a bit beyond the scope of this question, but there's probably some good introductory resources out there for programmers moving from one to the other.

Comment: @Zinki I'll check them out, definitely!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++, `5 > x > 1` is grouped as `(5 > x) > 1`.

`(5 > x)` is either `false` or `true`, and this is therefore never greater than 1, since `false` and `true` convert to `0` and `1` respectively. Hence

```
5 > x > 1
```

is `false` in C++, for any value of `x`. So in C++ you need to write the expression you really want with the longer form

```
x > 1 && x < 5
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm never satisfied with **you can't** option... So theoretically **you can** overload operators like this (just a sketch but I think you'll get the point):

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct TwoWayComparison {
    T value;
    bool cond = true;

    friend TwoWayComparison operator >(const T& lhs, const TwoWayComparison& rhs) {
        return {rhs.value, lhs > rhs.value};
    }
    friend TwoWayComparison operator >(const TwoWayComparison& lhs, const T& rhs) {
        return {rhs, lhs.cond && lhs.value > rhs};
    }
    operator bool() {
        return cond;
    }
};

int main() {
    TwoWayComparison<int> x{3};
    if (15 > x > 1) {
        std::cout << "abc" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[[live demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jzOmfpc1rqPVWs7M)